# Capistrano deploy source

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

When I'm calling bundle exec cap deploy with a git repository defined in deploy.rb, but without a branch definition, I noticed that it deploys from current branch.

Does it deploy from my local branch or from the remote branch?

Answer (score 0):

It will deploy from your remote branch

Answer (score 0):

It depends what version of Capistrano you are using.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Which versions use the remote branch and which use the local one?

Comment: There are two version of Capistrano in circulation v2 and v3, they are incompatible, and the differences between them are huge.